# $T A = LU$ solution for $Ax=b$ in $O(n^2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ and $T$ be two non-singular, $n\times n$ real matrices. Furthermore, suppose we are given two matrices $L$ and $U$ such that $L$ is unit lower triangular, $U$ is upper triangular, and
$$T A = LU$$
Write an algorithm that will solve the problem
$$Ax = b$$
for any given vector $b$ in $O(n^2)$ complexity. First explain briefly yet clearly why your algorithm requires only $O(n^2)$ flops (you may assume without proof that solving an upper triangular or a lower triangular system requires only $O(n^2)$ flops).

I can solve this as
$$A=T^{-1}LU$$
so
$$Ax=b\rightarrow T^{-1}LUx=b$$
$$x=U^{-1}L^{-1}Tb$$
**But I don't think this is $O(n^2)$.**

Comment: Why not? The only operations for computing $x$ are matrix-vector multiplication and two triangular solves.

Comment: That's true... I guess I was thinking about the inverting of T... But I don't need that for x. Thanks! I agree it looks good now.